# Pagination links disappear when clicked on any page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using CI pagination.On home page it is showing correct number of pages and their links but when I click on any page on the next page links become disappear.Here is my code , I am using Search , Sort together in a function

Controller

```
function projects($order_by="project_id", $sort_order="DESC", $term=0, $page=0, $rows=2){ 
        if(!isMemberLoggedIn()){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
        else{
            $member_id  =   "";
            if(!isSuperAdmin()){
                $member_id  =   $this->session->userdata('member_id');
            }

            if(isset($_POST['term'])){
                $term   =   $this->input->post('term');
            }

            $data['term']       = $term;
            $data['order_by']   = $order_by;
            $data['sort_order'] = $sort_order;

            $this->load->model('project_model', '', TRUE);

            $data['projects']   =   $this->project_model->getProjects(array('member_id'=>$member_id, 'term'=>$term, 'order_by'=>$order_by, 'sort_order'=>$sort_order, 'rows'=>$rows, 'page'=>$page));

            //echo '<pre>';print_r($data['projects']);die;
            //total number of projects

            $data['total']  =   $this->project_model->getProjects(array('member_id'=>$member_id, 'term'=>$term, 'order_by'=>$order_by, 'sort_order'=>$sort_order, 'rows'=>$rows, 'page'=>$page),true);

            $data['from_projects']  =   $page;

            $this->load->library('pagination');


            $config['base_url']         = site_url('admin/projects/'.$order_by.'/'.$sort_order.'/'.$term);
            $config['total_rows']       = $data['total'];
            $config['per_page']         = $rows;
            $config['uri_segment']      = 5;
            $config['first_link']       = 'First';
            $config['first_tag_open']   = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close']  = '</li>';
            $config['last_link']        = 'Last';
            $config['last_tag_open']    = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close']   = '</li>';

            $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
            $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></div>';
            $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close']    = '</a></li>';

            $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';

            $config['prev_link']        = '&laquo;';
            $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close']   = '</li>';

            $config['next_link']        = '&raquo;';
            $config['next_tag_open']    = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close']   = '</li>';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);


            $this->load->view('admin/projects',$data); 
        }
    }
```

And model

```
function getProjects($data=array(), $return_count=false)
    {
        if(empty($data))
        {
            //if nothing is provided return the whole shabang
            $this->getAllProjects();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->join('members','members.member_id=projects.member_id');

            if(!empty($data['member_id']))
            {
                $this->db->where('members.member_id',$data['member_id']);
            }

            //grab the limit
            if(!empty($data['rows']))
            {
                $this->db->limit($data['rows']);
            }

            //grab the offset 
            if(!empty($data['page']))
            {
                $this->db->offset($data['page']);
            }

            //do we order by something other than category_id?
            if(!empty($data['order_by']))
            {
                //if we have an order_by then we must have a direction otherwise KABOOM
                $this->db->order_by($data['order_by'], $data['sort_order']);
            }

            //do we have a search submitted?
            /****if(!empty($data['term']))
            {
                $search = json_decode($data['term']);
                //if we are searching dig through some basic fields
                if(!empty($search->term))
                {
                    $this->db->like('name', $search->term);
                    $this->db->or_like('hover_name', $search->term);
                    $this->db->or_like('description', $search->term);
                    $this->db->or_like('excerpt', $search->term);
                    $this->db->or_like('sku', $search->term);
                }

                if(!empty($search->category_id))
                {
                    //lets do some joins to get the proper category products
                    $this->db->join('category_products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id', 'right');
                    $this->db->where('category_products.category_id', $search->category_id);
                    $this->db->order_by('sequence', 'ASC');
                }
            }****/

            if($return_count)
            {
                return $this->db->count_all_results('projects');
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->db->get('projects')->result();
            }

        }
    }
```

And last view is as follows

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?> &nbsp;
```

Please help me guys how to sort it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The create_links() function returns an empty string when there is no pagination to show.**

[Pagination Class : Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

**Updated answer:**

Seems like something is wrong with `$config['total_rows']       = $data['total'];`

`$config['total_rows']`  => This number represents the total rows in the result set you are creating pagination for. Typically this number will be the total rows that your database query returned.

In your case, `$config['total_rows']` equals to rows to be shown on current page.

```
$data['total']  =   $this->project_model
                         ->getProjects(
                            array(
                                    'member_id'=>$member_id, 
                                    'term'=>$term, 
                                    'order_by'=>$order_by, /* Remove this */
                                    'sort_order'=>$sort_order, /* Remove this */
                                    'rows'=>$rows,  /* Remove this */
                                    'page'=>$page) /* Remove this */
                            ,true);
```

Remove the mentioned array indices.

`Sort order` and `order by` are not required for calculating total_rows. It doesn't make any sense. And `$page` and `$rows` are for limiting the rows to be shown on current page. These two parameter won't let you get exact `total_rows`.

Comment: I have 3 records and I am using 2 per page when I go on first page then there must be link to come back to first page. Do you agree ?

Comment: thats great now it is showing links on second page perfectly but I am facing one more problem.Now from home page I can click on second page and can go on second page but on the second Page I can not click on first page.Please solve this also and thanks for that

Comment: I did it.My $config['uri_segment'] was wrong it must be 6.Thanks for your help

Comment: That is because you are messing with `$config['uri_segment']` and `$config['base_url']`. Hit and trial yourself.